# R: How to replace list of names by list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list

I want to convert a list of dataframes's names to a list of dataframes.

Example:

```
datalist <- list("mtcars","swiss","iris")
```

Then I want to do something like

```
for(i in 1:length(datalist)) {
 datalist[[i]] <- parse(datalist[[i]])
}
```

So when I run `datalist[[i]]` I see the same as this

```
> mtcars
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

and not

```
> datalist[[i]]
"mtcars"
```

Comment: `lapply(datalist, function(x) eval(as.name(x)))` would do.  Forget `parse` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `get`:

```
datalist <- list("mtcars","swiss","iris")

dfList <- lapply(datalist, get)

for(i in 1:length(dfList)) {
  print(head(dfList[[i]]))
}

#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

#          Fertility Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
# Courtelary        80.2        17.0          15        12     9.96             22.2
# Delemont          83.1        45.1           6         9    84.84             22.2
# Franches-Mnt      92.5        39.7           5         5    93.40             20.2
# Moutier           85.8        36.5          12         7    33.77             20.3
# Neuveville        76.9        43.5          17        15     5.16             20.6
# Porrentruy        76.1        35.3           9         7    90.57             26.6

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 4):

`mget` is the appropriate function. It works on a character vector of object names and returns a list of objects. I use `unlist` to convert your list to a character vector:

```
mget(unlist(datalist))
```

Note that this will not work on the built-in data frames in your example unless (a) you set the `inherits` option to `TRUE` like this: `mget(unlist(datalist), inherits = TRUE)`, or (b) they have already been loaded into the global environment (e.g., using `data()`).

One advantage of `mget` compared to other answers proposed here is that the resulting list is created with the names of the objects as the names of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
parse(datalist[[i]])
```

use:

```
eval(parse(text = datalist[[i]]))
```

You need to evaluate the output of parse.